# Django Rest Framework | How to create a new product with Category name not ID

Tags: python, reactjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have two models created in Django. I am trying to send post request from react frontend using axios API call.

My react is working fine and I can post request using category id but not with category name ( either hardcoded or from the dropdown list)

I tried using Postman, I get the same result.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    upc = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from .models import Product
from .serializers import ProductSerializers
from rest_framework import generics


class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializers

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.all()

        return queryset

class ProductDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializers
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
```

Serializers.py

```
from .models import Product, Category
from rest_framework import serializers


class CategorySerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields="__all__"

class ProductSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_category_name')
    
    def get_category_name(self, obj):
        if obj.category_id:
            return obj.category.name

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am sending post request from react axios.
`axios.post(productListURL, data)`

How do I send post request with category name:

```
name:"Coca Cola" ,
category:"Beverage"
```

Instead of

```
name: "Coca Cola",
category: 1
```

Comment: try sending it with a key: `'category__name': 'Beverage'`

Comment: Thanks @Nealium. It didn't work I still have to pass ID for category.

Comment: Have you try `SlugRelatedField` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as the Product serializer

```
class ProductSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(), slug_field="name"
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields =['upc','name','description','category,'quantity','price']
```

Comment: Thanks @narravabrion. This worked for me. Do you recommend any Django rest framework doc/tutorial  other than official DRF.

Comment: Hey @AjayGC I'm glad I could help. Would you please mark the answer as correct. When learning I used [the veryacademy django/drf playlist](https://www.youtube.com/c/veryacademy/playlists). He explains concepts well and in detail